# git - change environment variable on branch checkout

Tags: git

I'd like to know what's a good practice of changing the value of an environment variable when doing `git checkout <branchname>` and give it a value depending on `branchname` (while having a default value in case no specific value is given for the checked out branch).

Eg. to get database names:

```
> git checkout dev
> echo $MYVAR
db_name_for_dev
> git checkout newfeaturebranch
> echo $MYVAR
db_name_for_newfeaturebranch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`$GIT_DIR/hooks/post-checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)

Answer (score 0):

We have a .bat script (on windows) that sets most ENV variables for the project, and then executes a program passed as argument.
We open our IDE and our command line prompt via this .bat file which is versioned in git.

Other than that I guess you could alias git checkout, point it to a script that does the checkout and then changes the ENV variables.

I prefer option 1.